# In RDF4H (Haskell), how can I get missing triples?

Tags: haskell, rdf

I'm trying to parse RDF/XML files using the Haskell library RDF4H. I can parse a file using functions like these:

```
parseRDFXML :: String -> IO (Either ParseFailure (RDF TList))
parseRDFXML = parseFile (XmlParser Nothing Nothing)

parseRDFXML' :: String -> IO (Either ParseFailure (RDF AdjHashMap))
parseRDFXML' = parseFile (XmlParser Nothing Nothing)
```

and then inspect the resulting contents using `ghci`:

```
parsed <- parseRDFXML "testRDF.xml" 
result = fromEither parsed
result
```

and it will print the triples that it's parsed. However, certain fields appear to be missing. I don't see the `dcterms:subject` field, for instance, or the `dcterms:language` field.

Am I doing something wrong?

For reference, here's an example of the type of RDF data I'm trying to parse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rdf:RDF xml:base="http://www.gutenberg.org/"
  xmlns:dcam="http://purl.org/dc/dcam/"
  xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
  xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
  xmlns:cc="http://web.resource.org/cc/"
  xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
  xmlns:pgterms="http://www.gutenberg.org/2009/pgterms/"
>
  <pgterms:ebook rdf:about="ebooks/15233">
    <dcterms:language>
      <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="N30b5232d06364953b02811ebc0debbb9">
        <rdf:value rdf:datatype="http://purl.org/dc/terms/RFC4646">en</rdf:value>
      </rdf:Description>
    </dcterms:language>
    <dcterms:subject>
      <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="N83c641d289c446b685ac37fd15845219">
        <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/terms/LCC"/>
        <rdf:value>DA</rdf:value>
      </rdf:Description>
    </dcterms:subject>
    <dcterms:type>
      <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="N23dc05dbba734cf28488df2f004510ea">
        <rdf:value>Text</rdf:value>
        <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/terms/DCMIType"/>
      </rdf:Description>
    </dcterms:type>
    <dcterms:subject>
      <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="N2b00277514604edc806f20cd6a653ba6">
        <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/terms/LCSH"/>
        <rdf:value>Nelson, Horatio Nelson, Viscount, 1758-1805 -- Death and burial</rdf:value>
      </rdf:Description>
    </dcterms:subject>
    <dcterms:subject>
      <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="N6d259d12d18c483db348bc0a0b45374a">
        <rdf:value>Admirals -- Great Britain -- Biography</rdf:value>
        <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/terms/LCSH"/>
      </rdf:Description>
    </dcterms:subject>
    <dcterms:publisher>Project Gutenberg</dcterms:publisher>
    <dcterms:issued rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2005-03-02</dcterms:issued>
    <dcterms:hasFormat>
      <pgterms:file rdf:about="http://www.gutenberg.org/files/15233/15233-8.txt">
        <dcterms:isFormatOf rdf:resource="ebooks/15233"/>
        <dcterms:modified rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">2013-03-16T14:52:48</dcterms:modified>
        <dcterms:format>
          <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="Nd5c53a6431ee4a81a124a068af6cc9cc">
            <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT"/>
            <rdf:value rdf:datatype="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT">text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1</rdf:value>
          </rdf:Description>
        </dcterms:format>
        <dcterms:extent rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">115988</dcterms:extent>
      </pgterms:file>
    </dcterms:hasFormat>
    <dcterms:rights>Public domain in the USA.</dcterms:rights>
    <dcterms:creator>
      <pgterms:agent rdf:about="2009/agents/5934">
        <pgterms:name>Beatty, William</pgterms:name>
        <pgterms:deathdate rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">1842</pgterms:deathdate>
        <pgterms:birthdate rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">1773</pgterms:birthdate>
        <pgterms:webpage rdf:resource="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Beatty_(surgeon)"/>
      </pgterms:agent>
    </dcterms:creator>
    <pgterms:bookshelf>
      <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="N8d8ab517be5d4d24a574a79c302445fc">
        <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="2009/pgterms/Bookshelf"/>
        <rdf:value>Napoleonic(Bookshelf)</rdf:value>
      </rdf:Description>
    </pgterms:bookshelf>
    <dcterms:hasFormat>
      <pgterms:file rdf:about="http://www.gutenberg.org/files/15233/15233.zip">
        <dcterms:format>
          <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="N0e16578584f8435998fb74335e273497">
            <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT"/>
            <rdf:value rdf:datatype="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT">text/plain; charset=us-ascii</rdf:value>
          </rdf:Description>
        </dcterms:format>
        <dcterms:modified rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">2013-03-16T14:55:02</dcterms:modified>
        <dcterms:extent rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">42991</dcterms:extent>
        <dcterms:isFormatOf rdf:resource="ebooks/15233"/>
        <dcterms:format>
          <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="Nef4e065fb0b14e2e9d2f7ff919015e27">
            <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT"/>
            <rdf:value rdf:datatype="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT">application/zip</rdf:value>
          </rdf:Description>
        </dcterms:format>
      </pgterms:file>
    </dcterms:hasFormat>
    <dcterms:hasFormat>
      <pgterms:file rdf:about="http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233.txt.utf-8">
        <dcterms:isFormatOf rdf:resource="ebooks/15233"/>
        <dcterms:extent rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">115955</dcterms:extent>
        <dcterms:format>
          <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="N00d1a7671ac647abad35d2ee8cdc7b6c">
            <rdf:value rdf:datatype="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT">text/plain</rdf:value>
            <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT"/>
          </rdf:Description>
        </dcterms:format>
        <dcterms:modified rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">2017-03-08T03:35:35.071213</dcterms:modified>
      </pgterms:file>
    </dcterms:hasFormat>
    <dcterms:hasFormat>
      <pgterms:file rdf:about="http://www.gutenberg.org/files/15233/15233-h.zip">
        <dcterms:extent rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">414933</dcterms:extent>
        <dcterms:isFormatOf rdf:resource="ebooks/15233"/>
        <dcterms:format>
          <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="N639c8cfe3790493fbd031ccb3cef1290">
            <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT"/>
            <rdf:value rdf:datatype="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT">text/html; charset=iso-8859-1</rdf:value>
          </rdf:Description>
        </dcterms:format>
        <dcterms:modified rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">2013-03-16T14:54:03</dcterms:modified>
        <dcterms:format>
          <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="N3d06273dd12f4c14b4b2c406185c19f2">
            <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT"/>
            <rdf:value rdf:datatype="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT">application/zip</rdf:value>
          </rdf:Description>
        </dcterms:format>
      </pgterms:file>
    </dcterms:hasFormat>
    <pgterms:downloads rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">24</pgterms:downloads>
    <dcterms:title>Authentic Narrative of the Death of Lord Nelson</dcterms:title>
    <dcterms:hasFormat>
      <pgterms:file rdf:about="http://www.gutenberg.org/files/15233/15233-h/15233-h.htm">
        <dcterms:modified rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">2013-03-16T14:52:30</dcterms:modified>
        <dcterms:isFormatOf rdf:resource="ebooks/15233"/>
        <dcterms:format>
          <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="N1640a362e5804551a11f14ad2afcbba6">
            <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT"/>
            <rdf:value rdf:datatype="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT">text/html; charset=iso-8859-1</rdf:value>
          </rdf:Description>
        </dcterms:format>
        <dcterms:extent rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">133225</dcterms:extent>
      </pgterms:file>
    </dcterms:hasFormat>
  </pgterms:ebook>
  <cc:Work rdf:about="">
    <cc:license rdf:resource="https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/"/>
    <rdfs:comment>Archives containing the RDF files for *all* our books can be downloaded at
            http://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Gutenberg:Feeds#The_Complete_Project_Gutenberg_Catalog</rdfs:comment>
  </cc:Work>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Beatty_(surgeon)">
    <dcterms:description>Wikipedia</dcterms:description>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

and here's what it parses:

```
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233.kindle.images") (UNode "rdf:type") (UNode "pgterms:file")
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233.kindle.images") (UNode "dcterms:extent") (LNode (TypedL "983557" "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"))
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233.kindle.images") (UNode "dcterms:modified") (LNode (TypedL "2017-03-08T03:35:37.901165" "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime"))
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233.kindle.images") (UNode "dcterms:isFormatOf") (UNode "ebooks/15233")
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/15233/15233.txt") (UNode "rdf:type") (UNode "pgterms:file")
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/15233/15233.txt") (UNode "dcterms:extent") (LNode (TypedL "115997" "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"))
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/15233/15233.txt") (UNode "dcterms:modified") (LNode (TypedL "2013-03-16T14:52:45" "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime"))
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/15233/15233.txt") (UNode "dcterms:isFormatOf") (UNode "ebooks/15233")
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/") (UNode "rdf:type") (UNode "cc:Work")
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/") (UNode "rdfs:comment") (LNode (PlainL "Archives containing the RDF files for *all* our books can be downloaded at\n            http://www.guten
berg.org/wiki/Gutenberg:Feeds#The_Complete_Project_Gutenberg_Catalog"))
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/") (UNode "cc:license") (UNode "https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/")
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233.kindle.noimages") (UNode "rdf:type") (UNode "pgterms:file")
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233.kindle.noimages") (UNode "dcterms:extent") (LNode (TypedL "232677" "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"))
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233.kindle.noimages") (UNode "dcterms:modified") (LNode (TypedL "2017-03-08T03:35:38.567127" "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime")
)
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233.kindle.noimages") (UNode "dcterms:isFormatOf") (UNode "ebooks/15233")
Triple (UNode "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Beatty_(surgeon)") (UNode "dcterms:description") (LNode (PlainL "Wikipedia"))
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233.epub.noimages") (UNode "rdf:type") (UNode "pgterms:file")
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233.epub.noimages") (UNode "dcterms:extent") (LNode (TypedL "50633" "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"))
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233.epub.noimages") (UNode "dcterms:modified") (LNode (TypedL "2017-03-08T03:35:36.364187" "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime"))
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233.epub.noimages") (UNode "dcterms:isFormatOf") (UNode "ebooks/15233")
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/15233/15233-8.txt") (UNode "rdf:type") (UNode "pgterms:file")
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/15233/15233-8.txt") (UNode "dcterms:extent") (LNode (TypedL "115988" "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"))
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/15233/15233-8.txt") (UNode "dcterms:modified") (LNode (TypedL "2013-03-16T14:52:48" "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime"))
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/15233/15233-8.txt") (UNode "dcterms:isFormatOf") (UNode "ebooks/15233")
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233") (UNode "dcterms:creator") (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/2009/agents/5934")
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233") (UNode "pgterms:downloads") (LNode (TypedL "24" "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"))
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233") (UNode "rdf:type") (UNode "pgterms:ebook")
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233") (UNode "dcterms:rights") (LNode (PlainL "Public domain in the USA."))
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233") (UNode "dcterms:issued") (LNode (TypedL "2005-03-02" "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date"))
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233") (UNode "dcterms:title") (LNode (PlainL "Authentic Narrative of the Death of Lord Nelson"))
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233") (UNode "dcterms:license") (UNode "license")
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233") (UNode "dcterms:publisher") (LNode (PlainL "Project Gutenberg"))
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233") (UNode "dcterms:hasFormat") (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233.kindle.images")
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233") (UNode "dcterms:hasFormat") (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/15233/15233.txt")
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233") (UNode "dcterms:hasFormat") (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233.kindle.noimages")
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233") (UNode "dcterms:hasFormat") (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233.epub.noimages")
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233") (UNode "dcterms:hasFormat") (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/15233/15233-8.txt")
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233") (UNode "dcterms:hasFormat") (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/15233/15233-h/15233-h.htm")
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233") (UNode "dcterms:hasFormat") (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/15233/15233.zip")
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233") (UNode "dcterms:hasFormat") (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233.epub.images")
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233") (UNode "dcterms:hasFormat") (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233.rdf")
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233") (UNode "dcterms:hasFormat") (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/15233/15233-h.zip")
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233") (UNode "dcterms:hasFormat") (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/15233/15233-8.zip")
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233") (UNode "dcterms:hasFormat") (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233.txt.utf-8")
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/15233/15233-h/15233-h.htm") (UNode "rdf:type") (UNode "pgterms:file")
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/15233/15233-h/15233-h.htm") (UNode "dcterms:extent") (LNode (TypedL "133225" "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"))
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/15233/15233-h/15233-h.htm") (UNode "dcterms:modified") (LNode (TypedL "2013-03-16T14:52:30" "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime"))
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/15233/15233-h/15233-h.htm") (UNode "dcterms:isFormatOf") (UNode "ebooks/15233")
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/15233/15233.zip") (UNode "rdf:type") (UNode "pgterms:file")
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/15233/15233.zip") (UNode "dcterms:extent") (LNode (TypedL "42991" "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"))
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/15233/15233.zip") (UNode "dcterms:modified") (LNode (TypedL "2013-03-16T14:55:02" "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime"))
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/15233/15233.zip") (UNode "dcterms:isFormatOf") (UNode "ebooks/15233")
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233.epub.images") (UNode "rdf:type") (UNode "pgterms:file")
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233.epub.images") (UNode "dcterms:extent") (LNode (TypedL "418975" "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"))
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233.epub.images") (UNode "dcterms:modified") (LNode (TypedL "2017-03-08T03:35:36.010256" "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime"))
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233.epub.images") (UNode "dcterms:isFormatOf") (UNode "ebooks/15233")
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233.rdf") (UNode "rdf:type") (UNode "pgterms:file")
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233.rdf") (UNode "dcterms:extent") (LNode (TypedL "13704" "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"))
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233.rdf") (UNode "dcterms:modified") (LNode (TypedL "2017-03-16T05:39:06.392075" "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime"))
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233.rdf") (UNode "dcterms:isFormatOf") (UNode "ebooks/15233")
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/15233/15233-h.zip") (UNode "rdf:type") (UNode "pgterms:file")
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/15233/15233-h.zip") (UNode "dcterms:extent") (LNode (TypedL "414933" "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"))
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/15233/15233-h.zip") (UNode "dcterms:modified") (LNode (TypedL "2013-03-16T14:54:03" "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime"))
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/15233/15233-h.zip") (UNode "dcterms:isFormatOf") (UNode "ebooks/15233")
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/15233/15233-8.zip") (UNode "rdf:type") (UNode "pgterms:file")
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/15233/15233-8.zip") (UNode "dcterms:extent") (LNode (TypedL "42996" "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"))
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/15233/15233-8.zip") (UNode "dcterms:modified") (LNode (TypedL "2013-03-16T14:54:55" "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime"))
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/15233/15233-8.zip") (UNode "dcterms:isFormatOf") (UNode "ebooks/15233")
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/2009/agents/5934") (UNode "rdf:type") (UNode "pgterms:agent")
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/2009/agents/5934") (UNode "pgterms:deathdate") (LNode (TypedL "1842" "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"))
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/2009/agents/5934") (UNode "pgterms:name") (LNode (PlainL "Beatty, William"))
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/2009/agents/5934") (UNode "pgterms:webpage") (UNode "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Beatty_(surgeon)")
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/2009/agents/5934") (UNode "pgterms:birthdate") (LNode (TypedL "1773" "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"))
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233.txt.utf-8") (UNode "rdf:type") (UNode "pgterms:file")
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233.txt.utf-8") (UNode "dcterms:extent") (LNode (TypedL "115955" "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"))
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233.txt.utf-8") (UNode "dcterms:modified") (LNode (TypedL "2017-03-08T03:35:35.071213" "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime"))
Triple (UNode "http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15233.txt.utf-8") (UNode "dcterms:isFormatOf") (UNode "ebooks/15233")
```

Comment: This is being tracked as a tracked bug on GitHub in the [rdf4h](https://github.com/robstewart57/rdf4h) library: https://github.com/robstewart57/rdf4h/issues/48

Comment: I'll close this, since it's tracked as a bug.

Comment: Actually, nevermind, I don't know how to close a question for that reason.